# ue4: cannot debug source code in a private path

Tags: unreal-engine4

I can debug source code when the file locates in a public path, e.g. Runtime/Renderer/Public/SceneView.h

[image: image for code in a public path]

But, I cannot debug source code when the file locates in a private path, e.g. Runtime/Renderer/Private/SceneRendering.h

[image: image for code in a private path]

Does anybody know why and how to solve the problem?

P.S. renderer.build.cs has set OptimizeCode as CodeOptimization.Never to enable debug

Answer (score 0):

Solved, pdb can be forcely enabled in target file